# compare two xml files for and update certain key only with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, zabbix, xmlstarlet, xmlupdate

I am trying to compare two of xml files and update only for a certain key as a new file. The issue occurs when i export a zabbix template and try to import on the other environment, status should be left as destination one. Assume that i have two xml files,

source.xml

```
<zabbix_export>
    <version>5.0</version>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <name>zabbix</name>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <templates>
        <template>
            <template>testtemp</template>
            <name>testtemp</name>
            <groups>
                <group>
                    <name>zabbix</name>
                </group>
            </groups>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <name>test1</name>
                    <key>kernel.maxproc</key>
                    <triggers>
                        <trigger>
                            <expression>{last()}=0</expression>
                            <name>testtrig1</name>
                        </trigger>
                        <trigger>
                            <expression>{last()}=100</expression>
                            <name>testtrig2</name>
                        </trigger>
                    </triggers>
                </item>
            </items>
        </template>
    </templates>
</zabbix_export>
```

destination.xml

```
    <version>5.0</version>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <name> zabbix </name>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <templates>
        <template>
            <template>testtemp</template>
            <name>testtemp</name>
            <groups>
                <group>
                    <name>zabbix</name>
                </group>
            </groups>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <name>test1</name>
                    <key>kernel.maxproc</key>
                    <triggers>
                        <trigger>
                            <expression>{last()}=0</expression>
                            <name>testtrig1</name>
                            <status>DISABLED</status>
                        </trigger>
                    </triggers>
                </item>
            </items>
        </template>
    </templates>
</zabbix_export>
```

So my goal would be to create a new file and put the key/value "DISABLED" as following.

final.xml

```
<zabbix_export>
    <version>5.0</version>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <name>zabbix</name>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <templates>
        <template>
            <template>testtemp</template>
            <name>testtemp</name>
            <groups>
                <group>
                    <name>zabbix</name>
                </group>
            </groups>
            <items>
                <item>
                    <name>test1</name>
                    <key>kernel.maxproc</key>
                    <triggers>
                        <trigger>
                            <expression>{last()}=0</expression>
                            <name>testtrig1</name>
                            <status>DISABLED</status>
                        </trigger>
                        <trigger>
                            <expression>{last()}=100</expression>
                            <name>testtrig2</name>
                        </trigger>
                    </triggers>
                </item>
            </items>
        </template>
    </templates>
</zabbix_export>
```

I've found one of the closest way to achieve this behave on the post [Updating two xml file using xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48933855/updating-two-xml-file-using-xmlstarlet) but still needs a small touch. So seems better to use 'xmlstarlet' since i need to run this babe in Debian natively.

It would be great at least give a clue how to use it in that way.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `destination.xml` isn't XML unless you insert `<zabbix_export>` at start of file. In `final.xml` `//group[1]/name` is from `source.xml` but `//trigger[1]` is from `destination.xml`; explanation? What [tag:xmlstarlet] command did you attempt?

Comment: only difference between two xml is `<status>DISABLED</status>` tag so all i want to insert this tag into final.xml if destination has it.

Comment: If the only difference between destination and final is that final has `<status>DISABLED</status>`, why not check if destination has the tag and, if so, just use destination as final (that is, make a copy of destination and call it "final")?

Comment: it depends. the thing is i have to insert `<status>DISABLED</status>` for certain upper key, in that case, for trigger named `<name>testtrig1</name>` but all other `<trigger>`. so need to figure out for delta also.

Comment: basically, if a trigger DISABLED on the destination but in the source, the final.xml should also be DISABLED for involved trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to solve it, both *assume* that

- `trigger` elements have unique `name`s
- a POSIX shell is used

First, an XSLT 1.0 transformation which will add a `status` element
from a same-named `trigger` in `destination.xml`. It's a basic
[identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)
which modifies the appropriate `trigger`s. In case you want to limit
to certain status values you could add, for example,
 `and $dstat = "DISABLED"` to the `xsl:if test` clause.

```xsl
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="ddoc" select="'destination.xml'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="dtt" select="document($ddoc)//triggers/trigger"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="triggers/trigger[not(status)]">
    <xsl:variable name="dstat" 
        select="$dtt[name = current()/name]/status"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:if test="string($dstat)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$dstat"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Run as

```sh
xsltproc --stringparam ddoc destination.xml delta.xsl source.xml > final.xml
```

or

```sh
xmlstarlet tr delta.xsl -s ddoc=destination.xml source.xml > final.xml
```

---

Second, to do the same in [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) shorthand is trickier since
there are limitations on both the `xmlstarlet select` and `xmlstarlet edit`
operations: the former doesn't copy entire input, the latter doesn't
accept conditionals (except in XPath expressions). However, using
`select` as a code generator to produce an `edit` command is possible.
(To list the generated XSLT 1.0 code add `-C` option before `-t`.)

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t \
  --var sq -o "'" -b \
  --var dq -o '"' -b \
  --var ddoc="'destination.xml'" \
  --var dtt='document($ddoc)//triggers/trigger' \
  -o 'xmlstarlet edit \' -n \
  -m '//triggers/trigger[not(status)]' \
    --var dstat='$dtt[name = current()/name]/status' \
    --if 'string($dstat)' \
      -o ' -s ' -v 'concat($sq,"//triggers/trigger[name=",$dq,current()/name,$dq,"]",$sq)' \
      -o ' -t elem -n status -v ' -v 'concat($sq,$dstat,$sq)' -o ' \' -n \
    -b \
  -b -f -n source.xml
```

For each `status`-less `trigger` in `source.xml` this command looks up
the same-named element in `destination.xml` having a non-empty `status`
element; on match emits an `-s` (subnode) clause for `xmlstarlet edit`
to target the appropriate node in `source.xml`. `-o` outputs literal
text, `-n` a newline, `-f` the input pathname, `-b` ends current
container (`-m`, `--if`, `--var`). Variables `sq` and `dq` assist in
quoting

Output:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
 -s '//triggers/trigger[name="testtrig1"]' -t elem -n status -v 'DISABLED' \
source.xml
```

Run as

```sh
xmlstarlet-sel-command-above | sh -s > final.xml
```

to execute the output as a shell script.